# Angular list/detail view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm wondering how to go about creating a list/detail view using Angular routes as what I currently have doesn't seem to be working.

The app has a list of 'projects' and when you click on a project you see a detailed view of that selected project, standard stuff. I've got this working using `ng-switch` but ideally I want to use seperate routes for the list/detail views. I've read that for this I'm going to need to use a `factory` method but I'm having difficulty passing the selected data between the routes. Here's what I have:

```
app.factory('Project', [ function ($rootScope) {
    var _selectedProject = {};
    _selectedProject.project = {};
    return _selectedProject;
}]);

app.controller('GalleryController', ['$scope', function ($scope, _selectedProject) {

    $scope.sharedProject = _selectedProject || {};

    $scope.selectProject = function (proj) {
        _selectedProject.project = proj;
    };

    $scope.$watch('sharedProject', function (proj) {
        $scope.chosenProject = proj;
    })


}]);
```

I'm actually getting cannot set property 'property' of undefined which is inside `$scope.selectedProject`.

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do, you are accessing _selectedPorject property when it's null...

Comment: in my HTML there's an ng-repeat and on each li item is an ng-click handler which performs $scope.selectProject and passes through the project in the array. I want to be able to then access that selected project info in the single view, both views use the same controller

Comment: can you try:

    $scope.selectProject = function (proj) {
     if (_selectedProject == null)
     {
        _selectedProject  = { "project": proj };
     }
     else
     {
       _selectedProject.project = proj;
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution for this is [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

`ui-router` allows the nesting of states which correspond to controllers, urls and html templates.

In your example I would do the following:

1. Install ui-router (described in the link above)
2. Apply a configuration as follows:

   ```
   myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider
       .state('project', {
         url: "/project",
         templateUrl: "partials/project/list.html",
         controller: project_list_controller
       })
       .state('project.details', {
         url: "/details",
         templateUrl: "partials/project/details.html",
         controller: project_detail_controller
       })
   }
   ```
3. Split your current controller into a project list controller and a project details controller.
4. Finally I would use a service to store your `selectedProject` as its a singleton, see the correct useage and differences between services and factories in this helpful [blog post](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You named your factory `Project` but are using `_selectedProject` as the injection to controller. You also  didn't include it in the injection array

Controller should look more like:

```
app.controller('GalleryController', ['$scope','Project', function ($scope, Project) {

    $scope.sharedProject = Project || {};

    $scope.selectProject = function (proj) {
        Project.project = proj;
    };

    $scope.$watch('sharedProject', function (proj) {
        $scope.chosenProject = proj;
    });

}]);
```